# How to send data from Ryu controller to Host

Tags: controller, network-programming, sdn, ryu

I'm wanting to send a string from Controller to a host in Ryu controller. I need send a String inside the packet-out but the documentation isn't clear about it. I've tried some solutions, but i can't do it.

Comment: Why do you want to send data from an sdn controller to a host, what is your scenario? SDN controllers communicate with switches not hosts.

Comment: Because I receive data from cliente and I wanto to send this data to other controller ( to do authentication of cliente).

Comment: The scenario is a network which a User trying to authentication himself but the process is distribuited

Comment: Which openflow switch are you using? Hosts don't send data to controllers, switches do. You need a flow on openflow switch, for example if you you use 802.1x authentication you need a eapol flow (ETH_TYPE:eapol). After that, if host sends eapol message to switch (it is the authentication request), switch asks the controller to send this packet. You can forward this packet to a port that other application is connected.

Answer (score 0):

Following the comments, you can setup any means of IPC if the two controllers are on same PC or a TCP socket if on different PCs but same network.